# DocuSign event notification Callback not working

Tags: docusignapi, envelope

I am trying to include the URL in my envelope for eventNotification callback like this:

```
  EventNotification eventNotification = new EventNotification();

        try
        {
            eventNotification.Url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocusignCallbackURL"];
            eventNotification.LoggingEnabled = "true";
            eventNotification.RequireAcknowledgment = "true";
            eventNotification.UseSoapInterface = "false";
            eventNotification.IncludeCertificateWithSoap = "false";
            eventNotification.SignMessageWithX509Cert = "false";
            eventNotification.IncludeDocuments = "true";
            eventNotification.IncludeEnvelopeVoidReason = "true";
            eventNotification.IncludeTimeZone = "true";
            eventNotification.IncludeSenderAccountAsCustomField = "true";
            eventNotification.IncludeDocumentFields = "true";
            eventNotification.IncludeCertificateOfCompletion = "true";

            envDef.EventNotification = eventNotification;

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error(ex);
        }
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be working.  I see nothing in my application logs and nothing in the logs in DocuSign.  Is there something else necessary to make this work?  Is there possibly setup in my account for taking the URL from the envelope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not telling DocuSign which events you want to be notified about.

You need to specify at least one event for which you'll receive notifications. There are two sets of potential notifications. (You can use both sets if you wish.)

See the elements `envelopeEvents` and `recipientEvents`

Also note that your url must start with `https://`

Comment: Thanks this was the answer.